# How to partition variable length vectors via mathematica's neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

I need to partition variable length vectors in neural network recently. For instance, the network input is `{1,2,3,4,...,2n}`, I want to partition two elements as a group, so the result seems like `{{1,2},{3,4},...,{2n-1,2n}}`, and notice that the input is variable length vectors.

I have tried to use `ReshapeLayer[]` to do this, the code like `ReshapeLayer[{Automatic,2},"Input"->{"Varying"}]`, and received the message,  `ReshapeLayer::valfail: Validation failed for ReshapeLayer: with variable-length inputs, Automatic can only be used if the product of known input dimensions is a multiple of the product of known output dimensions.`

So how can I do this via mathematica neural network? Is there anyway?

### Update

Thank you bro @Alexey Golyshev, but I still meet a problem, it seems that this method doesn't work inside a network.

What I want to do is, extract atom feature vectors according to my indexes, and partition two of them as a group.

Network inputs, Atom: `Dimensions@Atom={n1,8}`. NearIndex: `Dimensions@NearIndex={n2,1}`.

Full code:

```
enc=NetChain[{Ramp},"Input"->NetEncoder[{"Function", Partition[#,2] &, {"Varying",2,8}}]]
net=NetGraph[
    {"Near"->ExtractLayer[],
    "NearAtom"->enc},
    
    {NetPort["Atom"]->NetPort["Near","Input"],
    NetPort["NearIndex"]->NetPort["Near","Position"],
    "Near"->"NearAtom"}
]

atom1=Table[i,{i,12},{j,8}];
atom2=Table[i,{i,24},{j,8}];
index1=Partition[Range[4],1];
index2=Partition[Range[6],1];

output=net[<|"Atom"->{atom1,atom2},"NearIndex"->{index1,index2}|>]
```

Then return the message `NetGraph::tyfail2: Inferred inconsistent ranks for output of layer "Near" (a rank-3 array versus a matrix).`

Network output dimensions should be:

```
Dimensions/@output
```

> {{2,2,8},{3,2,8}}

Comment: Please show us the complete code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
enc = NetEncoder[{"Function", Partition[#, 2] &, {"Varying", 2}}]
```

[image]

```
net = NetChain[
  {
   Ramp
   },
  "Input" -> enc
  ]
```

[image]

```
net@Range[10]
```

> {{1., 2.}, {3., 4.}, {5., 6.}, {7., 8.}, {9., 10.}}

**UPDATE**

```
net = NetGraph[
  <|
   1 -> ExtractLayer["Input" -> {"Varying", 2, 8}, "Output" -> {"Varying", 2, 8}]
   |>,
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> NetPort[1, "Input"],
   NetPort["Position"] -> NetPort[1, "Position"]
   },
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Function", Partition[#, 2] &, {"Varying", 2, 8}}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
atom1 = Table[i, {i, 12}, {j, 8}];
atom2 = Table[i, {i, 24}, {j, 8}];
index1 = Partition[Range[4], 1];
index2 = Partition[Range[6], 1];
```

```
net[<|"Input" -> {atom1, atom2}, "Position" -> {index1, index2}|>]
```

[image]

```
Dimensions /@ %
```

> {{4, 2, 8}, {6, 2, 8}}

Comment: Thanks bro, and I want to do extract first, then partition, so the output dimensions should be {{2,2,8},{3,2,8}}, is there any way? very thanks!

Comment: Hello! I don't think that's possible.